# onCreate not a constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper, but I need it for getIntet

Tags: android, oncreate, sqliteopenhelper

I need to use the getIntent, but can't do so because from what I undertand, it is not a constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper, and getIntent needs to be used from within an onCreate.

This being the case,how would I get access to it from within the SQLiteOpenHelper?

Basically, I am trying to get the following code to work from within the SQLiteOpenHelper, but am having troubles.

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sortTypePassed=getIntent().getStringExtra(SmithRockScreenActivity.SORT_TYPE_VAR);
    }
```

I'm trying to do a query sort of the database, based on the value of String.  Like so:

```
  public Cursor getCursor() {



    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

    String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_YDSRATING, COLUMN_ROUTETYPE, COLUMN_AREA, COLUMN_ROUTEVIDEO, COLUMN_ROUTEDESCRIPTION};

    if (sortTypePassed.equals("nameSort")) { 

        Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(dbSqlite, asColumnsToReturn, null,
                null, null, null, "route_name ASC");

        return mCursor;

    } else {

        Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(dbSqlite, asColumnsToReturn, null,
                null, null, null, "yds_rating ASC");

        return mCursor;

    }
```

Here is the code in its entire length:

```
package com.pocketbeta;


import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;


class SmithRockDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public String sortTypePassed = "null";

private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.pocketbeta/databases/";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="smithrockdb.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "SmithRockRoutes";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "route_name";
public static final String COLUMN_YDSRATING = "yds_rating";
public static final String COLUMN_QUALITY = "quality";
public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "route_photo";
public static final String COLUMN_ROUTEVIDEO = "route_video";
public static final String COLUMN_TICKLIST = "ticklist";
public static final String COLUMN_AREA = "area";
public static final String COLUMN_ROUTETYPE = "route_type";
public static final String COLUMN_ROUTEDESCRIPTION = "route_description";

public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;

private final Context myContext;

public SmithRockDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    // check if exists and copy database from resource
    //createDB();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // check if exists and copy database from resource

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void createDatabase() {
    createDB();
}

private void createDB() {

    boolean dbExist = DBExists();

    if (!dbExist) {

        //By calling this method we create an empty database into the default system location
        //We need this so we can overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        //now we copy the database we included!
        copyDBFromResource();


    }



}    

private boolean DBExists() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try {
        String databasePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
        db.setVersion(1);



    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        Log.e("SqlHelper", "database not found");

    }

    if (db != null) {


        db.close();

    }


    return db != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDBFromResource() {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String dbFilePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    try {

        inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file.");

    }

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    dbSqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (dbSqlite != null)
    {
        dbSqlite.close();
    }
    super.close();

}

// NEED TO GET THIS CODE TO WORK TO BRING IN VALUE FROM OTHER INTENT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

//  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//  onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//  sortTypePassed=getIntent().getStringExtra(SmithRockScreenActivity.SORT_TYPE_VAR);
//}
// }


public Cursor getCursor() {



    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

    String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_YDSRATING, COLUMN_ROUTETYPE, COLUMN_AREA, COLUMN_ROUTEVIDEO, COLUMN_ROUTEDESCRIPTION};

    if (sortTypePassed.equals("nameSort")) { 

        Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(dbSqlite, asColumnsToReturn, null,
                null, null, null, "route_name ASC");

        return mCursor;

    } else {

        Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(dbSqlite, asColumnsToReturn, null,
                null, null, null, "yds_rating ASC");

        return mCursor;

    }

}


public String getName(Cursor c) {


    return(c.getString(1));

}

public String getRating(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(2));
}
public String getArea(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(4));
}
public String getRouteVideo(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(5));
}
public String getRouteDescription(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(6));
}

public String getRouteType(Cursor c) {

    String routeValue="";
    routeValue=(c.getString(3));
    String noSelection = "";

    if (routeValue != null) {
        return c.getString(3);

    } else {
        return(noSelection);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you are trying to accomplish overall? Are you trying to pass a value to perform a query? If you are trying to getIntent() from SQLiteOpenHelper then something is not right as that class should be completely detached from your view. Your main activity should call your SQLiteOpenHelper class, not the other way around.

Comment: I need to sort the return of the database based on a variable value.  So, for instance if a user clicks a button on the main screen to sort by number, or sort by name.

Answer (score 0):

> This being the case,how would I get access to it from within the SQLiteOpenHelper?

Ideally, you don't get access to `getIntent()` from `SQLiteOpenHelper`. You implement a constructor on `SQLiteOpenHelper` (hint: you already have one) and you pass in whatever data it needs. Ideally, this does **not** involve passing in the activity, but rather values the activity obtains from wherever (e.g., `Intent` extras).

Comment: Yeah, I need to sort data in the SQLiteOpenHelper based on an external variable.  I'd have to write 3 different SQLitOpenHelpers to sort 3 different styles.  If I can do a variable check during the sort in the SQLiteHelper and sort accordingly, I can avoid having to write and refer to 3 different helpers.

Comment: @Adam: Then pass the value as a parameter into the constructor or whatever method you are calling to get it to do the query that involves your sorting.

Comment: @Adam Why not have a separate method such as getItems(string sortOrder)? Replacing items with whatever objects you are returning (getUsers, getPages, etc...). You are not limited to passing values in the constructor.

Comment: Got it fixed by changing the variable during the button press, and then checking the variable like so:   if (SmithRockScreenActivity.SORT_TYPE_VAR.equals("nameSort")) {